# jQuery: making a textarea slide out when rows are changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text area box that expands from 3 to 17 rows when the user enters so many characters as well as on a button click.

SetNewSize(); function is the called via onkeyup and expands the text area when the length becomes greater than 50.

morespace(); function is called via the button.

I would like to slide the box out when this happens, any ideas?

Thanks here is my code:

```
function SetNewSize(textarea){
if (textarea.value.length > 50)
{
    textarea.rows = 17;
}
else
{
    textarea.rows = 3;
}}

function morespace(){
var thetxt = document.getElementById('more').value;
var box = document.forms["myForm"]["comment"];
if(box.rows == 3)
{
    $("#emailme").fadeOut(800);
    box.rows = 17;
    document.getElementById('more').innerHTML = "less space?";
}
else
{
    $("#emailme").fadeIn(800);
    box.rows = 3;
    document.getElementById('more').innerHTML = "more space?";
}}
```

Comment: Could you please accept an answer from this question, or, if none of the answers are acceptable, please clarify the question?

Answer (score 3):

By "slide the box out", I'm guessing you mean animate it. While you may not be able to animate textarea rows in jQuery, you can animate the `height` of the textarea to give the user more room. For example, you trigger something like this:

```
$('#comment').animate({'height': '+=40'},200);
```

This will add 40 pixels of height every time it is triggered and it animates it smoothly. If you want to add a number rows, you could simply calculate how large you want the textarea to become and then animate it to that height.

Here's a [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/znVdL/) for this action and you may want to check out the [jQuery animate API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the quick answer is use something someone already made: https://github.com/gurglet/jQuery-Textarea-Autoresize-Plugin

But if you want to roll your own, I'll update my reply in a moment with the code you need.

Updated Answer:
Assuming you have this HTML:

```
<button id="emailme">Email me</button>
<form id="myForm">
    <input id="more" name="more" type="text">
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="3">

    </textarea>
</form>
```

You could then use this script:

```
(function(){
    var BIG = 17,
        SMALL = 3,
        currentSize = SMALL,
        changeSize = function(rows) {
            var $more = $("#more"),
                thetxt = $more.val(),
                $box = $("#comment"),
                currentRows = $box.prop("rows"),
                boxRowHeight = $box.height()/currentRows,
                newHeight = rows * boxRowHeight;

            if (rows === currentRows) return;       

            return $box.animate({'height': newHeight }, 500 , "swing", function(){
                $more.val((currentRows > rows) ? "more space?" : "less space?");
                $box.prop("rows", rows);
                currentSize = rows;
            }).promise();
        },
        setNewSize = function(event) {
            var $area = $(event.target);
            if ($area.val().length > 50 && currentSize === SMALL) {
                changeSize(BIG);
                currentSize = BIG ;
            } 
        };



    $("#comment").bind("keyup", setNewSize);

    $("#more").click(function(){
        if (currentSize === BIG) {
            $.when(changeSize(SMALL)).then(function(){
                $("#emailme").fadeIn(800);
            });
        }else{
            $.when(changeSize(BIG)).then(function(){
                $("#emailme").fadeOut(800);
            });            
        }

    });            
}​)();​
```

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/isochronous/fvtY7/

Answer (score -1):

You could also use jquery's attr() like so:

```
$('#comment').attr('rows', 17);
```

Where rows represent the attribute to cahnge and 17 the value to set.
To get the number of rows currently used you use:

```
   var rows = $('#comment').attr('rows');
```

Comment: The question here is how to make the change animated.